# Comboboxes causing crashes in scenebuilder and self made apps

Tags: javafx, combobox, crash, freeze, scenebuilder

I've been having this continueous problem with any scenebuilder (both Javafx and Gluon). Whenever I try to open a combobox or even the toolbar for Javafx scene builder the program Java just quits working and the program crashes.
The same happens when I add a combobox to any java app and try to open it.

I need a scene builder because it makes making desktop apps that much easier and not even my profs at school seem to know what the problem is.

http://prntscr.com/f9pc9m

This screen shows what happens, whenever I open anything that drops down the program freezes and on clicking somewhere else it shows what should've opened all black. I know this is a Jfoenix menu but that is not the problem it doesn't work without jfoenix either.

Anything Java related is up to date and has been re-installed already.

Comment: Do you see the same thing in your own JavfaFX applications as well as scene builder? (After all, Scene builder is written in JavaFX and these are just regular combo boxes.) If you write a simple JavaFX program just in Java and include a Combo Box, does the same thing happen when you run it? What platform are you running on?

Comment: Yes that crashes my own applications aswell. I code with netbeans, have al the latest java updates & use Windows 8.1.

Comment: So probably you should update the question, since it seems to have nothing to do with scene builder.

Comment: I Updated the question.

Comment: Sounds similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083286/combobox-crash-javafx-8-jdk-51). I don't see anything that matches in the bug database.

Comment: It does look very similar indeed, so downgrading my java would fix it..?

Comment: Well... I'm not sure about that; the fix is not clear. It seems to be *very* specific to certain hardware configurations. Just as a random guess, try running with a software graphics pipeline; use `java -Dprism.order=sw MyApplication`. (This is a completely random guess, btw).

Comment: So where would I add that command line? I have seen about those 'comamnd lines' (That's what they look like to me at least) but never actually used them so i'm not sure where to put it

Comment: You type that in on the command line to run your application (just for testing purposes, obviously the end user is not going to do that in real life). You can add the option in your IDE too: in Eclipse if you go to Run -> Run configurations, under the "Arguments" tab enter `-Dprism.order=sw` in the "VM arguments" area.

Comment: Still gives the same result...